# Hide my tooltips with localStorage, but in my script

Tags: javascript, jquery

With some help in Stackoverflow (I'm novice level 0 in JS), I have achieved that a div **gift** is shown when it fulfills a condition:

```
if(total > 999 && total < 2999) {
$('#gift').show();
```

And then show a tooltip, which will be hidden after 6 sec´s:

```
if(total > 999 && total < 2999) {
$('#gift').show();

$('.tooltip').show();
window.setTimeout(function(){
$('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
},6000);
}
```

OK, work well, but my interest now is that the tooltip is shown only once to the user, for which I have tried to use **localStorage**, but it does not work for me:

```
const showTooltip1=localStorage.getItem('tooltip');
  if(showTooltip1==='false'){
    $('.tooltip').hide();
}

// The section below is not of my interest in the script, but it may be

    /*
    $('#gift').on('click',function(){
    $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
    localStorage.setItem('tooltip','false');
    });
    */
```

What am I doing wrong here...?

It will be that the master-script (in each click) is firing the `.show ();` for the tooltip...?

Thanks in advance!

//-----------------------

**Full-Script:** (Without local Storage for tooltip )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function manageRegalo() {
        var totalStorage = Number(localStorage.getItem("total"));
        var total = Number($("#total").val().replace(".",""));
        if(totalStorage != null && total === 0) {
            total = totalStorage;
        }

        if(total > 999 && total < 2999) {
          $('#gift').show();
          $('.tooltip').show();
          window.setTimeout(function(){
          $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
          },6000);
        }

        else{
          $('#gift').hide();
        }
      }

        $(document).on('click', function (event) {
          const target = event.target;
          if (target.matches('.comp-clone') || target.matches('.bbp')) {
            manageRegalo();
            localStorage.setItem('total', Number($("#total").val().replace(".","")));
          }
        });
        manageRegalo();
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `window.localStorage`? ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Also, what does your `const showTooltip1=localStorage.getItem('tooltip');` log in the console?

Comment: **Chritheoreo** I have copied it from another `localStorage` on my practice page, but it does not work with the tooltip. Every time the main script reads that the condition is met  `if (total> 999 && total <2999)`  for the `#gift`, the tooltip appears again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicated what you're writing with `setItem`, so there's no way for us to know what `getItem` should be returning.

The logic you're after here is: If `getItem` returns `null`, show the tooltip and use `setItem` to put a value into localStorage so that *subsequent* checks will prevent the tooltip from showing.

You would need to modify your code along these lines:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('suppress_gift_tooltip') == null) {
      // Your unaltered tooltip code
      $('.tooltip').show();
      window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('.tooltip').fadeOut('slow');
      },6000);

      // Prevent subsequent display
      localStorage.setItem('suppress_gift_tooltip', 'true')
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, **meagar** Beautiful, clean and organized... +10, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The localstorage value will be null if you didn't assign the value. Better you can check with null and assign the boolean for further use.

```
if( !localStorage.getItem('toolTip') ) {
    // operation
    localStorage.setItem('toolTip',false);
}
```

The above condition will be true if toolTip item is not present in the localStorage and if the value of toolTip is false in the localStorage.

Comment: **Prashanth** I'm learning JS 20 days ago. There is a points that I do not know yet. Sorry (for me).

Comment: You can't store booleans in localStorage.

Comment: **@meagar** And that? https://www.competa.com/blog/storing-javascript-object-localstorage/